# How to use protoc generated .js file (from proto file) in NestJs gRPC?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, protocol-buffers, grpc

To share the proto files, I decide to publish the proto files using the npm package (to our private nexus repository manager)
First,  I using the following to generate the .js file form proto file:

```
protoc --proto_path=C:\Users\proto  --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:C:\Users\npm_release\src user.proto
```

user.proto:

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "google/protobuf/duration.proto";  
import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";
package li;

service TubeService{
  rpc GetUser (ID) returns (User){}
}

message ID{
    int32 id = 1;
}
message User{
    string type = 1;
}
```

then I get the user_pb.js:

```
// source: user.proto
/**
 * @fileoverview
 * @enhanceable
 * @suppress {missingRequire} reports error on implicit type usages.
 * @suppress {messageConventions} JS Compiler reports an error if a variable or
 *     field starts with 'MSG_' and isn't a translatable message.
 * @public
 */
// GENERATED CODE -- DO NOT EDIT!
/* eslint-disable */
// @ts-nocheck

var jspb = require('google-protobuf');
var goog = jspb;
var global = (function() { return this || window || global || self || Function('return this')(); }).call(null);

var google_protobuf_duration_pb = require('google-protobuf/google/protobuf/duration_pb.js');
goog.object.extend(proto, google_protobuf_duration_pb);
var google_protobuf_timestamp_pb = require('google-protobuf/google/protobuf/timestamp_pb.js');
goog.object.extend(proto, google_protobuf_timestamp_pb);
goog.exportSymbol('proto.li.ID', null, global);
goog.exportSymbol('proto.li.User', null, global);
/**
 * Generated by JsPbCodeGenerator.
 * @param {Array=} opt_data Optional initial data array, typically from a
 * server response, or constructed directly in Javascript. The array is used
 * in place and becomes part of the constructed object. It is not cloned.
 * If no data is provided, the constructed object will be empty, but still
 * valid.
 * @extends {jspb.Message}
 * @constructor
 */
proto.li.ID = function(opt_data) {
  jspb.Message.initialize(this, opt_data, 0, -1, null, null);
};
goog.inherits(proto.li.ID, jspb.Message);
if (goog.DEBUG && !COMPILED) {
  /**
   * @public
   * @override
   */
  proto.li.ID.displayName = 'proto.li.ID';
}
/**
 * Generated by JsPbCodeGenerator.
 * @param {Array=} opt_data Optional initial data array, typically from a
 * server response, or constructed directly in Javascript. The array is used
 * in place and becomes part of the constructed object. It is not cloned.
 * If no data is provided, the constructed object will be empty, but still
 * valid.
 * @extends {jspb.Message}
 * @constructor
 */
proto.li.User = function(opt_data) {
  jspb.Message.initialize(this, opt_data, 0, -1, null, null);
};
goog.inherits(proto.li.User, jspb.Message);
if (goog.DEBUG && !COMPILED) {
  /**
   * @public
   * @override
   */
  proto.li.User.displayName = 'proto.li.User';
}



if (jspb.Message.GENERATE_TO_OBJECT) {
/**
 * Creates an object representation of this proto.
 * Field names that are reserved in JavaScript and will be renamed to pb_name.
 * Optional fields that are not set will be set to undefined.
 * To access a reserved field use, foo.pb_<name>, eg, foo.pb_default.
 * For the list of reserved names please see:
 *     net/proto2/compiler/js/internal/generator.cc#kKeyword.
 * @param {boolean=} opt_includeInstance Deprecated. whether to include the
 *     JSPB instance for transitional soy proto support:
 *     http://goto/soy-param-migration
 * @return {!Object}
 */
proto.li.ID.prototype.toObject = function(opt_includeInstance) {
  return proto.li.ID.toObject(opt_includeInstance, this);
};


/**
 * Static version of the {@see toObject} method.
 * @param {boolean|undefined} includeInstance Deprecated. Whether to include
 *     the JSPB instance for transitional soy proto support:
 *     http://goto/soy-param-migration
 * @param {!proto.li.ID} msg The msg instance to transform.
 * @return {!Object}
 * @suppress {unusedLocalVariables} f is only used for nested messages
 */
proto.li.ID.toObject = function(includeInstance, msg) {
  var f, obj = {
    id: jspb.Message.getFieldWithDefault(msg, 1, 0)
  };

  if (includeInstance) {
    obj.$jspbMessageInstance = msg;
  }
  return obj;
};
}


/**
 * Deserializes binary data (in protobuf wire format).
 * @param {jspb.ByteSource} bytes The bytes to deserialize.
 * @return {!proto.li.ID}
 */
proto.li.ID.deserializeBinary = function(bytes) {
  var reader = new jspb.BinaryReader(bytes);
  var msg = new proto.li.ID;
  return proto.li.ID.deserializeBinaryFromReader(msg, reader);
};


/**
 * Deserializes binary data (in protobuf wire format) from the
 * given reader into the given message object.
 * @param {!proto.li.ID} msg The message object to deserialize into.
 * @param {!jspb.BinaryReader} reader The BinaryReader to use.
 * @return {!proto.li.ID}
 */
proto.li.ID.deserializeBinaryFromReader = function(msg, reader) {
  while (reader.nextField()) {
    if (reader.isEndGroup()) {
      break;
    }
    var field = reader.getFieldNumber();
    switch (field) {
    case 1:
      var value = /** @type {number} */ (reader.readInt32());
      msg.setId(value);
      break;
    default:
      reader.skipField();
      break;
    }
  }
  return msg;
};


/**
 * Serializes the message to binary data (in protobuf wire format).
 * @return {!Uint8Array}
 */
proto.li.ID.prototype.serializeBinary = function() {
  var writer = new jspb.BinaryWriter();
  proto.li.ID.serializeBinaryToWriter(this, writer);
  return writer.getResultBuffer();
};


/**
 * Serializes the given message to binary data (in protobuf wire
 * format), writing to the given BinaryWriter.
 * @param {!proto.li.ID} message
 * @param {!jspb.BinaryWriter} writer
 * @suppress {unusedLocalVariables} f is only used for nested messages
 */
proto.li.ID.serializeBinaryToWriter = function(message, writer) {
  var f = undefined;
  f = message.getId();
  if (f !== 0) {
    writer.writeInt32(
      1,
      f
    );
  }
};


/**
 * optional int32 id = 1;
 * @return {number}
 */
proto.li.ID.prototype.getId = function() {
  return /** @type {number} */ (jspb.Message.getFieldWithDefault(this, 1, 0));
};


/**
 * @param {number} value
 * @return {!proto.li.ID} returns this
 */
proto.li.ID.prototype.setId = function(value) {
  return jspb.Message.setProto3IntField(this, 1, value);
};





if (jspb.Message.GENERATE_TO_OBJECT) {
/**
 * Creates an object representation of this proto.
 * Field names that are reserved in JavaScript and will be renamed to pb_name.
 * Optional fields that are not set will be set to undefined.
 * To access a reserved field use, foo.pb_<name>, eg, foo.pb_default.
 * For the list of reserved names please see:
 *     net/proto2/compiler/js/internal/generator.cc#kKeyword.
 * @param {boolean=} opt_includeInstance Deprecated. whether to include the
 *     JSPB instance for transitional soy proto support:
 *     http://goto/soy-param-migration
 * @return {!Object}
 */
proto.li.User.prototype.toObject = function(opt_includeInstance) {
  return proto.li.User.toObject(opt_includeInstance, this);
};


/**
 * Static version of the {@see toObject} method.
 * @param {boolean|undefined} includeInstance Deprecated. Whether to include
 *     the JSPB instance for transitional soy proto support:
 *     http://goto/soy-param-migration
 * @param {!proto.li.User} msg The msg instance to transform.
 * @return {!Object}
 * @suppress {unusedLocalVariables} f is only used for nested messages
 */
proto.li.User.toObject = function(includeInstance, msg) {
  var f, obj = {
    type: jspb.Message.getFieldWithDefault(msg, 1, "")
  };

  if (includeInstance) {
    obj.$jspbMessageInstance = msg;
  }
  return obj;
};
}


/**
 * Deserializes binary data (in protobuf wire format).
 * @param {jspb.ByteSource} bytes The bytes to deserialize.
 * @return {!proto.li.User}
 */
proto.li.User.deserializeBinary = function(bytes) {
  var reader = new jspb.BinaryReader(bytes);
  var msg = new proto.li.User;
  return proto.li.User.deserializeBinaryFromReader(msg, reader);
};


/**
 * Deserializes binary data (in protobuf wire format) from the
 * given reader into the given message object.
 * @param {!proto.li.User} msg The message object to deserialize into.
 * @param {!jspb.BinaryReader} reader The BinaryReader to use.
 * @return {!proto.li.User}
 */
proto.li.User.deserializeBinaryFromReader = function(msg, reader) {
  while (reader.nextField()) {
    if (reader.isEndGroup()) {
      break;
    }
    var field = reader.getFieldNumber();
    switch (field) {
    case 1:
      var value = /** @type {string} */ (reader.readString());
      msg.setType(value);
      break;
    default:
      reader.skipField();
      break;
    }
  }
  return msg;
};


/**
 * Serializes the message to binary data (in protobuf wire format).
 * @return {!Uint8Array}
 */
proto.li.User.prototype.serializeBinary = function() {
  var writer = new jspb.BinaryWriter();
  proto.li.User.serializeBinaryToWriter(this, writer);
  return writer.getResultBuffer();
};


/**
 * Serializes the given message to binary data (in protobuf wire
 * format), writing to the given BinaryWriter.
 * @param {!proto.li.User} message
 * @param {!jspb.BinaryWriter} writer
 * @suppress {unusedLocalVariables} f is only used for nested messages
 */
proto.li.User.serializeBinaryToWriter = function(message, writer) {
  var f = undefined;
  f = message.getType();
  if (f.length > 0) {
    writer.writeString(
      1,
      f
    );
  }
};


/**
 * optional string type = 1;
 * @return {string}
 */
proto.li.User.prototype.getType = function() {
  return /** @type {string} */ (jspb.Message.getFieldWithDefault(this, 1, ""));
};


/**
 * @param {string} value
 * @return {!proto.li.User} returns this
 */
proto.li.User.prototype.setType = function(value) {
  return jspb.Message.setProto3StringField(this, 1, value);
};


goog.object.extend(exports, proto.li);
```

Next, to publish the npm package, I have the following package.json

```
{
"name" :"testnpm",
"version": "0.7.5",
"description": "Proto use",
"main": "src/index.js",
"author": "tesy",
"publishConfig": {
    "registry": "test"
}


  }
```

In the src folder, I have index.js and user_pb.js.
In the index.js:

```
var user = require('./user_pb')
module.exports.user = user
```

Then, I run npm publish, which pushes to the nexus.

In my nestjs project:

```
import { ClientOptions, Transport } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { user } from 'testnpm';
export const microserviceOptions: ClientOptions = {
  transport: Transport.GRPC,
  options: {
    url: '127.0.0.1:5790',
    package: 'li',
    protoPath: user,
  },
};
```

it would get error:

```
 ERROR [ClientProxy] The invalid gRPC package (package not found)
```

it seems that when I set the package filed to "li", nestjs can not find the package name in the user.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Check this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/nestjs-proto-gen-ts

this will help to generate TS file for Proto file that can be used in NestJs controller

```
tsproto --path ./protofolder
```